# Why does replacing a number of consecutive whitespaces also remove the line break in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Here's my code:

```
print apps_version
apps_version = re.sub("\s+"," ",apps_version)
print apps_version
apps_version = apps_version.splitlines()
```

And this is what happens:

```
backend    10.2.25
server   12.6.4.6
backend 10.2.25 server 12.6.4.6
```

It does replace the whitespaces with a single whitespace, but it also removes new line symbol from the end of the line. I solved it by replacing whitespace with | character and using that to split the lines, but can someone explain why does replacing whitespaces remove the line break? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this reference:

`\s` Matches any single space character. Equivalent to [`\t\r\n\v\f`].

[reference regex site](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re2.shtml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> `\s`
>
> When the [`UNICODE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) flag is not specified, it matches any whitespace character, this is equivalent to the set `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`. The [`LOCALE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.LOCALE) flag has no extra effect on matching of the space. If [`UNICODE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) is set, this will match the characters `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` plus whatever is classified as space in the Unicode character properties database.

`\s` matches more than just space (ASCII 32), it will also match horizontal tab, **new line**, **carriage return**, form feed and vertical tab. And **even more** if you enable `UNICODE` flag.

If space is all you care about, then `r' +'` is all you need.